# Curva de regressão com eixo x igual a 0

Tags: python, inteligência-artificial, regressão

Como faço para encontrar o valor que corta o eixo x de uma linha de regressão como mostrado no gráfico abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu dataframe tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
total_da_carga  data_ordinal
21708           737061
24845           737062
22696           737063
16433           737066
18238           737067
```

O campo data_ordinal corresponde ao deslocamento dos dias referentes a um período de tempo.

Preciso saber em qual data o valor da carga será igual a 0 pela tendência da curva de regressão linear.

```
IA_Carga_CDD = carga[['total_da_carga','data_ordinal']]
X = IA_Carga_CDD['total_da_carga']
y = IA_Carga_CDD['data_ordinal']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(x_train,y_train)
predictions = lm.predict(0)
Carga_zero = datetime.fromordinal(predictions)
```

Tentei fazer da forma acima, porém não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além da abordagem com `intercept_`, é possível fazer da forma que escreveu. Porém, vou levantar alguns pontos incorretos no seu código.

Em `lm.fit`, é preciso ajustar o formato do `x_train`.
Então, a maneira correta ficaria

```
lm.fit(x_train.values.reshape(-1,1), y_train)
```

Além disso, também é preciso ajustar o formato do input em `lm.predict`.

```
predictions = lm.predict([[0]])
```

Com esses ajustes, você obtém a data na sua variável `Carga_zero`

O resultado esperado com `random_state=42` no `train_test_split` é

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 17, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

O regressor `LinearRegression()` do sklearn tem o atributo `intercept_`, que retorna o `y` onde o regressor intercepta o eixo Y, ou seja, em `x = 0`. Inclusive, no exemplo da documentação do [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) é utilizado este atributo.

No seu exemplo, como o regressor chama `lm`, basta fazer:

```
lm.intercept_
```